# Should I pursue aviation?

Tags: general-aviation

I am a senior in high school who has been interested/fascinated in aviation. I do not know whether to go to a 4 year school to fly commercial for UPS or Fedex or do charter planes or fly for companies like menards. I am not sure of the benefits of either one. I’ve heard some work more days and some work less days. I just want to be committed on this before I spend a boat load of money for school.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! This is a good question but it isn't really a good fit for this particular site. We focus on questions that have a clear answer; open-ended and subjective questions work better on discussion forums, where you can get a range of opinions, ask follow-up questions and so on. As suggestions, you might try pilotsofamerica.com or reddit.com/r/flying. But do stick around and browse the training questions we have. The [tour] might be useful to help you with how the site works.

Comment: @user46189 I'd say spending the boat load of money is the measure of your commitment. If you hesitate with that one, this probably is not the job for you. Aviation is a highly competetive career, and it'll be years before you've paid for your training unless you were born loaded. There's no fast tracking for success.

Comment: You really need to talk to a few pilots.  People don't just get jobs with majors and a lot of folks don't like flying charter.  The job is tedious, only occasionally exciting, and ultimately very fickle. I found out that I really like flying but only on my schedule.  I don't like being evaluated every six months and I don't like flying when I don't want to.  Consider getting a high paying job and just buying a plane.